# Запятая перед И (после двоеточия)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, двоеточие

Нужна ли запятая перед И?

"Каждый понимал: был бой и то, что они долетели, — настоящее чудо".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***(1)Каждый понимал: (2) был бой и  (3) то, что они долетели, — настоящее чудо.***

1. Сложное предложение состоит **из трех простых**.  Между предложением  (1) и  предложениями (2) и (3) бессоюзная связь,  одиночный союз  И связывает предложения (2) и (3).

Предложение (1)  относится **к обоим предложениям**, связанным союзом И. Если поставить запятую, то **связь будет нарушена**.

2. Поэтому это **классический вариант с  однозначным решением** по правилу Розенталя: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

**Перед союзом  И запятая не ставится,** если части сложносочиненного предложения объединены **общим элементом**. Общей может быть поясняемая двумя частями сложносочиненного предложения **третья часть,** предшествующая им и связанная с ними бессоюзной связью: Берегов не видать: их скрыла ночь и оттолкнули куда-то широкие волны разлива (М. Г.);

3. Единственная трудность –  **определение грамматики предложения (3).**   Это нестандартный вариант простого предложения.  В позиции подлежащего находится сочетание "то, что они долетели", а сказуемым является существительное "чудо".

Comment: Sharon, хочу уточнить (может, я неправильно понимаю). Мне кажется, что здесь 4 предложения, и инверсии нет. _"То – настоящее чудо"_ (подлежащее _ТО_, сказуемое _ЧУДО_, каждый ведь понимал не _чудо_, а именно _ТО_, которое объясняется придаточным _"что они долетели"_. Насчет подлежащего и сказуемого (инверсии) можно сомневаться, я не настаиваю, но то, что в последнее предложение вклинивается придаточное, вроде не вызывает вопросов...

Comment: Да правильно вы понимаете, я просто не стала углубляться в эту тему, но немного поправлю текст.  Внутренняя структура этого предложения не так важна, поэтому его удобно приравнять к  простым предложениям, чтобы применить правило. Если я сейчас начну считать все основы, то  это мало что даст, а объяснение  не будет таким ясным. Кстати, в простом предложении местоимение ТО можно опустить: Что они долетели - это настоящее чудо.

Comment: Sharon, я почему-то почувствовал, что вы сделали так, чтобы не усложнять.

Comment: @Sharon, мне кажется, что я нашла **оригинальное** предложение. _Не нужно было быть экспертом или военным, чтобы понять, что был бой и то что они долетели, настоящее чудо_ (С. Алексеенко. На окраинах империума). https://www.litres.ru/sergey-aleksenko/iz-cikla-rasskazov-na-okrainah-imperiuma-chast-3-okolo-no/chitat-onlayn/

Comment: @Римма Михайлова  Римма, что-то мне не очень нравится оформление этого предложения. Недаром его изменили.